# How to call DocuSign Clickwrap API from an LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying to embed a DocuSign Elastic Wrap (formally ClickWrap) into a LWC. This embeds fine in an apex page.

**Apex page example:**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" controller="ContactJs">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
      <title>SLDS Responsive Design Visualforce Page in Salesforce Mobile and DocuSign</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

       <!-- Import the Design System style sheet -->
       <apex:slds />
    </head>
    <body>

      <!-- REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->
      <div class="slds-scope">

        <!-- PRIMARY CONTENT WRAPPER -->

          <!-- RESPONSIVE GRID EXAMPLE -->
          <div class="myapp">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
              <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-1 slds-small-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4">
                <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around--x-small">Box 1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-1 slds-small-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--3-of-4">
                <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around--x-small">Box 2</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- / RESPONSIVE GRID EXAMPLE -->
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
  <div id="ds-clickwrap"></div>
    <script
    src="https://eu.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var x;
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        //Invoking controller action getcon
        "{!$RemoteAction.ContactJs.getcon2}",
        function (result, event) {
            console.log("in the func");
            if (event.status) {
                console.log('the event status is ' + event.status); 
                console.log('the event result is ' + result); 
                x = result;
                docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render(
                    {
                        environment: "https://eu.docusign.net",
                        accountId: "abcdef",
                        clickwrapId: '123456',
                        clientUserId: result,
                        documentData: {
                            fullName: "",
                            email: x,
                            company: "",
                            title: "",
                            date: "",
                        },
                    },
                    "#ds-clickwrap"
                );
            }
        }
    );
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

but I am not able to achieve the same thing yet in the LWC equivalent:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="DocuSign Example with LWC"> 
        Hello World - Test!
            <div id="ds-clickwrap"></div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

and

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import docusign from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/docusign';

export default class ElasticAgreement1 extends LightningElement {

    renderedCallback() {

        loadScript(this, docusign).then(() =>
            console.log('files loaded'))

        docusign.docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render({
            environment: 'https://eu.docusign.net',
            accountId: 'abcdef',
            clickwrapId: '123456',
            clientUserId: 'ABC 123',
            documentData: {
                fullName: 'Full Name',
                email: 'Email',
                company: 'Company',
                title: 'Job Title',
                date: 'Date'
            }
        }, '#ds-clickwrap');
    }
}
```

The returned error is:

*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Clickwrap')*

I am calling the docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render object correctly, surely?